# Javascript replace multiple chars at once

Tags: javascript, unicode, replace

Here is my array and string:

```
var array = new Array('üÜ', 'ıI', 'iİ', 'ğĞ', 'şŞ', 'çÇ');
var string = 'İSTANBUL, ÜSKÜDAR, Çarşamba'
```

I'd to replace every (for ü) to [üÜ]. I mean [üÜ]SK[üÜ]DAR. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace()` method

```
string.replace(/ü|Ü/g, '[üÜ]')
```

For all matches,

```
array.forEach(function(key){
    string = string.replace(new RegExp('['+ key +']', 'g'), '['+ key +']');
});
```

Comment: how can i replace all chars in array with this method?

Comment: I though you can figure out from this part. Ok let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceAll(source, search, replace, ignoreCase) {
    //SCAPE SPECIAL CHARACTERES.
    var search1 = search.toString().replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    //IGNORE CASE SENSIVITY.
    var ignore = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
    var result = source.replace(new RegExp(search1, ignore), replace);
    return result;
}


var array = new Array('üÜ', 'ıI', 'iİ', 'ğĞ', 'şŞ', 'çÇ');

for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i] = replaceAll(array[i],"ü", "üÜ",true);
}
```